# Rails, how to use searchlogic to reorder returned objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

So I have had various forms of this working in the last while, but never all working together.

for reference I have categories / Brands / Products, with the right relationships working:  the site is http://emeraldcityguitars.com to see it in action.

So in my brands controller show action:

```
    @category = Category.find_by_url_name(params[:category_id])
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
    @search = Product.brand_id_equals(@brand.id).category_id_equals(@category.id).descend_by_price
    @products = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

this works fine, as is evidenced in my log:

```
  Category Load (25.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "categories" 
  Category Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."url_name" = 'acoustic-guitars') LIMIT 1
  Brand Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 14) 
  Product Load (4.8ms)   SELECT * FROM "products" WHERE ((products.category_id = 3) AND (products.brand_id = 14)) ORDER BY products.price DESC LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0
  SQL (0.2ms)   SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "products" WHERE ((products.category_id = 3) AND (products.brand_id = 14)) 
   Rendering template within layouts/application
   Rendering brands/show
```

You can see that its grabbing products descending by price.

In my Brand#show I am doing the following:

```
 <%- form_for [@category, @brand], :html => {:method => 'get', :id => 'sort_form', :class => 'sort_form'} do -%>
          <label>Sort by: </label> <%= select_tag :order, product_sort_options %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
        <%- end -%>
```

The goal being that a user could sort by a couple different options.

I also have this in my products_helper:

```
def product_sort_options
    options_for_select([
      ['', nil],
      ['Newest to Oldest', 'descend_by_date'],
      ['Oldest to Newest', 'ascend_by_date'],
      ['Price: Highest to Lowest', 'descend_by_price'],
      ['Price: Lowest to Highest', 'ascend_by_price'],
      ['Name', 'ascend_by_name']
    ])
  end
```

The issue I am having is that if I click the drop down and do price lowest to highest it reloads the page, with "?order=ascend_by_price" at the end of the url but there is no change in the order of the products.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add in a call to include the value of your `:order` parameter. It only gets included in the search by default if you're doing something like `Product.search(params[:search])` (and the order parameter would then have to be in `params[:search][:order]`).

So, something like this should work:

```
@search = Product.brand_id_equals(@brand.id)
@search.category_id_equals(@category.id)
@search.order(params[:order] || :descend_by_price)
```

I've split it out to make it easier to read. The last line specifies to order by the value of your order parameter or the default ordering if that's not available.

Comment: I had to modify slightly but this did it.